# Are there any web based email clients written in python?

Tags: python, email

I need to integrate a email client in my current python web app.
Anything available?

L.E.: I'm building my app on top of CherryPy

Comment: Wow, a 9 year old question about a software recommendation and not closed up to now. You must be lucky. My questions about software recommendations get closed within the first minutes. BTW: I think question like this should be asked here, at StackOverflow and not moved away (to a dead end like http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Good point. The fact is this kind of question often does not even have a definite answer at the time of asking. And answers given nine years ago usually go stale or irrelevant. That make it not a good a fit for stackoverflow, which is more of a reference platform. Of course, at the time, this much was not obvious. Closing the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking up [webmail](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=webmail&submit=search) on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) gives [Posterity](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Posterity/).

There is very probably some way to build a webmail with very little work using [Zope3](http://www.zope.org/Products/Zope3) components, or some other CMS.

I guess if you are writing a webapp, you are probably using one of the popular frameworks. We would need to know which one to give a more specific answer.

Comment: If the framework is django, then what are the alternatives?

Comment: The project "Posterity" looks dead.

Answer (score 3):

For others who might find this thread, check out [Mailpile](http://www.mailpile.is/). I haven't used it yet, it is a python-based mail client, and I am sure it could be modified to work as a webmail app as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Quotient](https://launchpad.net/quotient).  It's a somewhat unusual webmail system, and it definitely won't fit into the same process as CherryPy - but it is in Python ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can build one, using [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) for generating and parsing mail, [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#module-imaplib) for reading (and managing) incoming mail from your mail server, and [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) for sending mail to the world.

Comment: Modding down because the question was "integrating an email client", not "writing an email client from standard library".

Comment: modded down for same reason